# how to require BLT package in TCL8.6?

Tags: tcl

I'm getting an error while doing "package require BLT" TCL in 8.6.

I downloaded BLT 3.0 and placed that in lib directory and still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to print your 'auto_path' variable and see if module is available in this path. If not, set it properly:

```
lappend auto_path <your_path_to_package_dir>
```

before calling 'package require'.

Comment: I did that, but this package needs to be installed first and installation is failing. I wandered if BLT2.5 and 3.0 are even supported in tcl 8.6.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `pkgIndex.tcl` file in the directory containing your newly-installed package. Look for lines containing `package ifneeded ...` in it. That will contain the exact name of the package for you to `package require`.

In my `blt2.5/pkgIndex.tcl` here the name is `BLT` and requiring it works:

```
> wish8.6 
% package require BLT
2.5
%
```

If the package can not be loaded in your case, print the `$errorInfo` after the failed `package require` -- it may contain a clue as to why the package failed to load.